# Update pandas dataframe without iterrows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have 2 dataframes such as:

```
 df1:
 index   x     y
 abc     DF    UK
 cde     DF    FR
 grt     FD    UK
```

and:

```
 df2:
 index   DF    UK    FR    FD
 abc     nan   nan   nan   nan
 cde     nan   nan   nan   nan
 grt     nan   nan   nan   nan
```

I would like to have a solution that sets the second data frame to be:

```
 df3:
 index   DF    UK    FR    FD
 abc     1     1     nan   nan
 cde     1     nan   1     nan
 grt     nan   1     nan   1
```

I tried to do:

```
df3.ix[df1.index, df1.ix[:,0]] = 1
df3.ix[df1.index, df1.ix[:,1]] = 1
```

This seems to put 1 in all rows for the columns in df3.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`pd.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```
pd.get_dummies(df1.set_index('index')).replace(0, np.nan)
df.columns = [c[2:] for c in df.columns]

        DF   FD   FR   UK
index                    
abc    1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0
cde    1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN
grt    NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0
```